# What are the secret commands in W▲TCH DOGS?

Tags: wtch-dogs

There's a bunch of secret codes in [W▲TCH DOGS](http://gamejolt.com/games/w-tch-dogs/17283) that do different things.

> -Secret Commands
>
> -Do these by holding down all the letters in the command
>
> ????: Makes a bunch of dogs
>
> ????: Kills all the dogs in your kennel
>
> selfie: Takes a screenshot
>
> ????: Secret Trophy (GameJolt Version only)

I determined pretty quickly that holding down the letters D O G S spawns hundreds of dogs the longer you hold them down, and made my way to the top of the leaderboard by almost half a million points.

There's achievements associated with the other codes I assume though, and I'd like to figure them out.

The only other thing I've noticed is that pressing R resets everything, so I guess you can't use it in a command?

Comment: Did you try `DEATH`?

Comment: I don't know if that just didn't work or if my keyboard just can't enter all those inputs at once, because it did the thing where it beeps when you hold down too many keys.

Comment: Maybe try `DIE` ?

Comment: If it beeps, it means you filled the input buffer. You need a better keyboard.

Comment: `DEATH` doesn't seem to do anything, or maybe it's just not immediately noticeable. I noticed holding R makes the game go weird and messes up the sound though...

Comment: Most keyboards can't handle holding down more than 2 or 3 keys at once. Once you go beyond that it depends on the internal wiring of the keyboard whether additional held down keys are recognized correctly. You can get gaming keyboards that have necessary wiring to support an unlimited number keys held down at once, though the USB versions are usually limited to 6 keys at once because of protocol issues.

Comment: I'd be willing to set up a macro to simulate the key presses, but I'm not gonna bother with that until I know what the other commands are.  I made my gamepad simulate the DOGS keypress and left a rubber band on the trigger for a while which is how I got such a high score in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the commands as follows:

**DOGS:** Makes a bunch of dogs as you hold it down.
**DIE:** Kills all the dogs in your kennel.
**SELFIE:** Takes a screenshot of your game.
**????:** Secret Trophy. *(I don't quite know this one yet, however I'll keep you updated on it if I find it)*